# .htaccess rewrite rule causing javascript error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, firebug

I have a strange problem, where if I write a rule to match any character (.*), firebug throws up a javascript syntax error.

The rule I have is:

```
RewriteRule ^news/story/(.*)? index.php?page=viewNews&story=$1 [L,NC]
```

The error that appears is:

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHT.../xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If I change the rule to be:

```
RewriteRule ^news/story/(\d+)? index.php?page=viewNews&story=$1 [L,NC]
```

It works fine, but only for numbers obviously.  I want it to work for text as well, hence the wildcard.

If I go to the index.php?page=viewNews&story=test+story page directly, it works fine.

Comment: Look in the firebug if html page returned for one of the linked script files on the page.

Comment: Firebug refers to a linked script, yes.  Taking that script out then brings the same error up for the next linked script, and so on.  If I take all javascript files out, it works.  But, I do not believe the javascript is at fault here, as there are no errors if I go direct to the url as I described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your javascripts are also contained in the path /news/story/* and that these requests are being rewritten.

You can fix this by setting a rewrite condition that will only rewrite if a file (or directory) doesn't exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^news/story/(.*)? index.php?page=viewNews&story=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: The javascript files are stored in /scripts.  I gave your conditions a go, but still the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Got it fixed.  You weren't far off!  The rule was correct, but my header file had a relative link to the scripts folder, which of course was being affected by the rewrite rule.

Comment: you probably still want to keep the rewrite conditions as above, though - unless you want to rewrite away from physical files.

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility would be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite=no [NC]
```

add this to your Conditions

and add a parameter to the files you dont want to have redirected

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js?rewrite=no"></script>
```